# How to get last child *ngFor list of components

Tags: css, angular

I got a component that is called users-list. Inside this component there is *ngFor of directory-user component.

```
<directory-user-card *ngFor="let directoryUser of directoryUsers"
  [directoryUser]="directoryUser">
```

I need the last directory-user-card component to have different style. So I tries to use last-child at the parent component but with no success.

```
directory-user-card :last-child{
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use `*ngFor` - `last` variable to check whether the element is the last element or not.

if it's a last element of the loop then `last` variable will become true, so we can use `[ngClass]` to add/remove the class.

[Angular Docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables)

[Github Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10856), where this is discussed as the correct way to handle this.

```
<directory-user-card *ngFor="let directoryUser of directoryUsers; let last = last"
  [directoryUser]="directoryUser" [ngClass]="{'last-child': last}">

.last-child{
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much Bear.. completely forgot about it :-)

Comment: i cant get this to work with css combinators for some reason, anyone else have this issue or a solution?

Comment: Thank you, this works perfect for me! @d0rf47: !important might solve your problem.

Comment: This has worked perfectly!